# getting data from facebook conversation api

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-graph-api

I have used graph api from facebook recently and it's so amazing and when I tried to get conversations data on my page it worked, but it gave me an object, I tried to use print_r for it and it looks like this

```
try {
// Get the \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
// If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
    $response = $fb->get('me/conversations?fields=name,messages{from,attachments{file_url,name,size},to,message,sticker},subject');

//    $response = (array) $response;

    print_r($response);
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
// When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

so for now I tried having the data alot of times, I don't want all of these data just I want the body of the request so I can take an object then access it normally, how can I do that

Comment: your question should be included in the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for that I have known how to do that, it is like this

```
$response = $fb->get('me/conversations?fields=messages{to,message,sticker,from}');
```

will be

```
$response = $fb->get('me/conversations?fields=messages{to,message,sticker,from}')->getdecodedBody();
```